# Using textblob or spacy for correction spelling in french

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, textblob

I would like to correct the misspelled words of a text in french, it seems that spacy is the most accurate and faster package to do it, but it's to complex,
I tried with textblob, but I didn't manage to do it with french words.

It works perfectly in english, but when I try to do the same in french I get the same misspelled words:

```py
#english words 
from textblob import TextBlob
misspelled=["hapenning", "mornin", "windoow", "jaket"]
[str(TextBlob(word).correct()) for word in misspelled]

#french words
misspelled2=["resaissir", "matinnée", "plonbier", "tecnicien"]
[str(TextBlob(word).correct()) for word in misspelled2]
```

I get this:

```
#english:
['happening', 'morning', 'window', 'jacket']

#french:
['resaissir', 'matinnée', 'plonbier', 'tecnicien']
```

Answer (score 11):

`textblob` supports only English. That's why it returns the French words as they are without any corrections. If you want to use it for French, then you need to install `textblob-fr`. BUT According to its official repository [here](https://github.com/sloria/textblob-fr), `textblob-fr` doesn't support spell checking.

Besides spaCy doesn't support spell checking with its language models. There is a workaround out there using `spacy_hunspell` that wraps `hunspell` (the spell checker of LibreOffice and Mozilla Firefox), but it doesn't support French either.

So, my recommendation is to use [`pyspellchecker`](https://pyspellchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which supports English, French, German, Spanish and Portugues... It can be installed easily via `pip` like so:

```
pip install pyspellchecker
```

### English

Here is how to use it with English:

```
>>> from spellchecker import SpellChecker
>>>
>>> spell = SpellChecker()
>>> misspelled = ["hapenning", "mornin", "windoow", "jaket"]
>>> misspelled = spell.unknown(misspelled)
>>> for word in misspelled:
...     print(word, spell.correction(word))
jaket jacket
windoow window
mornin morning
hapenning happening
```

### French

Here is how to use it with French... It's exactly the same as English with specifying the `langauge=fr`:

```
>>> from spellchecker import SpellChecker
>>>
>>> spell = SpellChecker(language='fr')
>>> misspelled = ["resaissir", "matinnée", "plonbier", "tecnicien"]
>>> misspelled = spell.unknown(misspelled)
>>> for word in misspelled:
...     print(word, spell.correction(word))
plonbier plombier
matinnée matinée
tecnicien technicien
resaissir ressaisir
```